# Custom Extension Help (entry_submission_absolute_end() hook)

Tags: channel-entries, channel, extension

I'm making a custom extension to add a channel entry's data to another remote database, but I only want to do this with certain channel(s).

How do I check inside my extension hook what channel the entry is being published in?

```
/**
* Adds new EE product to Infusionsoft products table.
*
* @return bool
*/
public function entry_submission_absolute_end() {

    // if the channel being published is "products", continue..


    // get the product details from the channel entry form
    $newRow = array(
        'ProductName' => '',
        'Description' => '',
        'ProductPrice' => ''
    );

    // add the new row(product) to the infusionsoft db
    if ($this->app->dsAdd('Product', $newRow)) {
        return true;
    }

} // END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook gets called with several parameters that you can add to your extension:

```
public function entry_submission_absolute_end($entry_id, $meta, $data, $view_url) {
  if ($meta['channel_id'] == 7) {
    // do your code here
```

See http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html#entry_submission_absolute_end

Comment: Thank you so much! This was perfect and worked as expected.